# R Markdown refuses to suppress code chunk output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to suppress a lattice density plot, while showing the code chunk in R Markdown. I am using the following code:

````
```{r, results = 'hide'}
densityplot(imputed_data)`
```
````

For some reason, when I knit the R markdown document to PDF or HTML, the plot appears below the code chunk. Are there other knitr display options of which I'm unaware that will suppress this plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`results = 'hide'` hides printed output while `fig.show = 'hide'` hides plots and figures.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much Sai! I was scratching my head on this one.